# Disprove $\overline{\overline{A}} \leq \overline{\overline{B}}$ implies that $A \subseteq B$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

Disprove $\overline{\overline{A}} \leq \overline{\overline{B}}$ implies that $A \subseteq B$

Counterexample: $A = \left \{1\right\}$ and $B = \left\{\varnothing\right\}$. $\overline{\overline{A}} = \overline{\overline{B}}$, but $A \nsubseteq B$.

Is this proof valid?

Comment: If $\overset{=}{A}$ means "cardinality", the example is correct.

Comment: Yes.  That proof is enough